# Generar modal en ciclo php error

Tags: php, html, modal

Hola que tal he estado intentando que se genere un modal por cada registro que tengo en una DB y no lo he conseguido, todo esto lo hago en un ciclo como lo muestro en este pedazo de código ( todos los datos que extraigo de la DB se extraen bien en el ciclo, es funcional ) el problema es que me gustaría que por cada fila de la tabla como lo muestro en el código se genere un modal con los datos de se registro, no se si me este explicando bien, el pedazo del código del modal no lo introduzco porque ya intente de varias maneras y si se genera pero se genera para todos con el primer registro de la DB a todos, supongo que todos mandan a llamar con el mismo boton a ese modal unico que se creo.

espero me puedan ayudar un saludo!

PD: solo introduzco un pedazo del codigo espero se entienda no creo que sea necesario partes del top o abajo.

```
 <tbody>

  <tr>

  <?php 

    include('../conx.php');

   $sql="SELECT * FROM dc";

  $resul=$link->query($sql);

  while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()):


                $i = $fila['id_img'];
                $n = $fila['nom'];
                $f = $fila['fnom'];

 ?>

    <td id="td1" > #CDC0<?= $i ?> </td>

    <td id="td1"> <?= $n ?>  </td>

    <td> <img src="../img/dc/<?= $f ?>" id="timg">   </td>

     <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data- 
 toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo"> 
  Actualizar </button> <button class="button-delete btn btn-danger" 
 type="button">Eliminar</button>  </td>



</tr>

 <?php endwhile; ?>

 </tbody>
```

Comment: No entiendo bien para que quieres hacer esto, pero creo que si lo haces con con javascript podrás lograr tu cometido.
Manda a pedir los resultados por ajax y recorre el arreglo para que puedas mostrar el modal por cada resultado como quieres.

Answer (score 0):

Hola no entendí muy bien lo que estas preguntando pero te quiero hacer una observaciones en el codigo para que podamos entenderlo mejor:

```
<?php 
/*-----  Conexion a la base de datos ------*/
    include('../conx.php');
   $sql="SELECT * FROM dc";
  $resul=$link->query($sql);
/*-----  Obtenemos todas los datos------*/
//cremos un arreglo
$datos = array();
//Obtenemos todas las filas
  while($fila=$resul->fetch_assoc()){
      $datos[] = $fila;
  }
 ?>
 <!--Comenzamos con el ciclo foreach $datos "simpre debe de ser array"-->
<?php foreach($datos as $elemento): ?>
    <!--Obtenemos el id de la imagen-->
    <td id="td1" > #CDC0 <?php echo elemento['id_img'];?> </td>
    <!--Obtenemos el Nombre de la imagen-->
    <td id="td1"> <?php echo elemento['nom'];?> </td>
    <!--Obtenemos la url de la imagen-->
    <td> <img src="../img/dc/<?php echo elemento['fnom'];?>" id="timg">   </td>
    <!--Colocamos el btn de la ventana modal-->
    <td> 
    <!--Colocamos el btn de Actulizar-->
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@mdo"> 
            Actualizar 
        </button> 
        <!--Colocamos el btn de Eliminar-->
        <button class="button-delete btn btn-danger" type="button">
            Eliminar
        </button>  
    </td>
<!--Esta TR y TBODY no se en donde comieza -->
</tr>
 </tbody>
 <!--Cerramos el ciclo-->
 <?php endforeach;  ?>
```

Para comenzar trata de comentar todo el codigo y orintarlo lo más posible para entenderlo. Las primeras llaves de PHP donde dice conexión a la base de datos yo lo pondría en un documento aparte como obtenerFilias.php y lo metería en una función y que te regresara un arreglo con todas las filas. Hice unas modificaciones para que quedara más claro el codigo solo que como no tengo todo el codigo no tengo manera de probarlo.

**Si me dieran adivinar la pregunta....**

Yo creo que no puedes hacer la ventanas modales porque todavía te falta demasiado codigo, yo te recomendaria que ocuparas Boostrap (que creo que ya lo ocupas) para rapido te dejo el enlace:

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/modal/

Copia el segundo ejemplo que trae la documentacion y si no te sale puede que sea porque no lo intalaste bien.

Se que a lo mejor puedes estar estresado porque no queda tu proyecto pero con calma tu puedes!!! Espero haberte ayudado y mucho exito.